# Receiving A Phone Number Input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio, twilio-api

The app sends a message using a REST API, but as it stands the "to" number is hard-coded into the app. I'd like that number to be a value inputted by the user.

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Joe's Web App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="words">
      <h1>My Name</h1>
      <p>
        Insert your number below to recieve a text!
      </p>
    </div>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="number">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</body>
```

Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

account_sid = 'AC26b29f734e8145f6df3497eb6ca50205'
auth_token = 'my auth token'

@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

@client.account.messages.create({
  :from => 'Twilio Number',
  :to => 'phone number',
  :body => 'Hey this is Joe!',
})
```

Comment: I think it would be simple if you build with rack. for more details.. https://codenoble.com/blog/ruby-web-applications-without-rails/

Comment: so you mean, you want to implement this in sinatra or what?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not entirely clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with a post route, if you want to use sinatra.

a raw code should be,

```
post '/send_message' do 
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
  @client.account.messages.create({
    from: 'Twilio Number',
    to: params[:number],
    body: 'Hey this is Joe!', 
  })

end
```